Register a self hosted agent in azure Devops without PAT
I want to use docker images as self-hosted agent in Azure Pipelines. Is there a way I can register these without PAT token? like, using managed identity? I have seen this URL:
Agent with Service Principal .
But It also talk about client secret. Also I want it run in non-interactive mode. Basically, I want to run my containers inside AKS cluster and register as agents without PAT.
I have tried with PAT token only so far, but have read that, managed identity also can be used. but confused with the service principal which need client secret.  Also in some document's it is specified that you still need PAT.

As you have seen this URL: Register an agent using a service principal, it mentioned that you can register an agent using a Service Principal starting with agent version 3.227.1 by specifying SP as the agent authentication option.
It seems that you are confused with the service principal which needs client secret.  You can refer this Use service principals & managed identities to learn more about how to use Microsoft Entra service principals and managed identities in your Azure DevOps Services organizations to grant access to your organization resources.
From this Authentication options of the self-hosted agent unattended config, we can see that if you chose to use Service Principal (--auth SP) as auth type, the required information is

--clientID <clientID> - specifies the Client ID of the Service Principal with access to register agents
--tenantId <tenantID> - specifies the Tenant ID which the Service Principal is registered in
--clientSecret <clientSecret> - specifies the Client Secret of the Service Principal

The sample unattended command of using auth type sp:
.\config.cmd --unattended --url https://dev.azure.com/orgname --auth sp --tenantId <tenantID>  --clientId <clientID>  --clientSecret <clientSecret> --agent <agent-name> --pool <agent-pool-name>

For more detailed instructions on running a self-hosted agent in Docker, you can refer to the Run a self-hosted agent in Docker documentation. You will just need to replace --auth pat with --auth sp.
Update:

As per the MS Documentation which you have provided, the start.sh has a section like below, which expects a token file. What I understood is the AZP_TOKEN env variable contains a PAT token. How do I get rid of this?
AZP_AGENT_PACKAGES=$(curl -LsS \ -u user:$(cat "${AZP_TOKEN_FILE}") \ -H "Accept:application/json" \ "${AZP_URL}/_apis/distributedtask/packages/agent?platform=${TARGETARCH}&top=1")

For this question, it is matching the Azure Pipelines agent and getting the download URL of the agent with the REST API request. We can also use the Service Principal to get a token and send the REST API request with it.
Here is the sample script to replace the "1. Determining matching Azure Pipelines agent..." section using Service Principal:
#!/bin/bash

# Define variables
tenantId="your-tenant-id"
clientId="your-client-id"
clientSecret="your-client-secret"
resource="499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798"  # Azure DevOps resource's UUID

# Create the request body
body="grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&resource=${resource}"

# Get the token
response=$(curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "${body}" "https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/token")

# Extract the access token from the response
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(echo $response | jq -r .access_token)

# Fetch agent packages using the access token
AZP_AGENT_PACKAGES=$(curl -LsS \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
    -H "Accept:application/json" \
    "${AZP_URL}/_apis/distributedtask/packages/agent?platform=${TARGETARCH}&top=1")

# Print the JSON response for debugging
echo "JSON Response: ${AZP_AGENT_PACKAGES}"

# Extract the latest agent package URL
AZP_AGENT_PACKAGE_LATEST_URL=$(echo "${AZP_AGENT_PACKAGES}" | jq -r ".value[0].downloadUrl")

if [ -z "${AZP_AGENT_PACKAGE_LATEST_URL}" -o "${AZP_AGENT_PACKAGE_LATEST_URL}" == "null" ]; then
  echo 1>&2 "error: could not determine a matching Azure Pipelines agent"
  echo 1>&2 "check that account \"${AZP_URL}\" is correct and the token is valid for that account"
  exit 1
fi

echo "Latest agent package URL: ${AZP_AGENT_PACKAGE_LATEST_URL}"


as per the MS Documentation which you have provided, the start.sh has a section like below, which expects a token file. What I understood is the AZP_TOKEN env variable contains a PAT token. How do I get rid of this?
AZP_AGENT_PACKAGES=$(curl -LsS 
-u user:$(cat "${AZP_TOKEN_FILE}") 
-H "Accept:application/json" 
"${AZP_URL}/_apis/distributedtask/packages/agent?platform=${TARGETARCH}&top=1")

Hi @jereeshthomas, I updated the answer with the way using the Service Principal to get the download URL of the agent. Please check the update in my answer. Thanks.

I  have connected But get the follwing error

Hi @jereeshthomas, can you please share the error message?

It is working. I got an error from the Listener code(.NET Exe ) used by the config.sh , it was not able to find the passed client secret , I was calling the config.sh in multiple lines as in the docs. As of now I changed it to a single line  and hardcoded the parameters for config.sh, in this way it is working, I  need to check with variables

Hi @jereeshthomas, glad to know that it is working. Please let me know if you need more help about the issue.

Hi @jereeshthomas, is it successful when you check with variables?

Tian , yes I am able to connect using variables

Hi @jereeshthomas, thanks for your update. In this way, we can use Service Principal (--auth SP) to register a self-hosted agent in azure DevOps without PAT.
